# Why isn't my bounty on top of the list of questions?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, bounty

Why isn't my bounty on top of the list of questions?

What should I do about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bounties are not posted on the top of the questions list. Rather they are highlighted on the featured questions list: https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/?tab=featured. The tab can be accessed on the main question list as shown in the screenshot below:

[image]

You can read more about bounties in the [help center](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/help/bounty).

Comment: The help center page can be misleading and should be corrected

Comment: Honestly confused, not trying to be snarky: What part of "The bountied question will appear with a special indicator in all question lists, and it will also be visible on the homepage Featured tab for 7 days." is misleading?

Comment: "a special indicator in all question lists ... for 7 days", where? 1. on the bottom (that doesn't make sense) 2. where it is now (that helps *alot*) 3. on top (that gives it attention)